# Метод call и его особенности

Tags: javascript

Метод вызывает функцию с новым значением `this` и переданными аргументами.
Приведу немного кода и постараюсь объяснить, что происходит:

```
let slice = Array.prorotype.slice;
slice.call([1,2,3])
```

Мы скопировали ссылку на метод `slice` в переменную. Далее вызываем метод. Однако, простой вызов `slice([1,2,3])` отработает некорректно, поскольку метод ожидает контекст извне. В этой связи мы, используя `call`, передаем нужный методу контекст и все работает.

Но я не очень хочу каждый раз передавать контекст. Поэтому делаю следующее:

```
slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);
```

Теперь можно вызывать метод без `call`:

```
slice([1,2,3]);
```

Все работает замечательно. Но проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как. Ведь метод `slice` принимает итерируемый объект в качестве `this`, судя по вызову `slice.call([1,2,3])` или `[1,2,3].slice()`. Когда мы добавляем контекст методу `call` через `bind` таким способом `slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice)` мы, по идее, возвращаем обертку в которой `this = Array.prototype.slice`. Ну и при следующем вызове `slice([1,2,3])` я ожидаю, что выполняется такой код `Function.prototype.call(Array.prototype.slice, [1,2,3])`. Тогда, каким образом это работает? В документации написано, что `Function.prototype.call` принимает первым аргументом контекст, а следующими аргументы функции. Но как он знает о самой функции? Понятно, когда мы на какой-то функции вызывает `call`, типа `slice.call`. А когда мы делаем это через прототип? У меня одна догадка, что, когда мы вызываем функцию `call` через прототип `Function.prototype.call`, то первым аргументом передаем саму функцию, вторым контекст и дальше аргументы. Но я нигде не могу нагуглить информацию, которая подтверждала бы мои догадки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на самом деле работает этот вызов:

```
slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите. call - это метод, для которого this - это любая функция.

Когда вы пишите вот так:

```
slice.call([1,2,3])
```

То для метода `slice` контекстом (this) становится массив `[1,2,3]`, а для метода `call` контекстом становится уже `slice`.

То же самое можно было бы написать и вот так:

```
call.call(slice, [1,2,3])
```

Когда вы пишите `call.bind(slice)` - вы фиксируете контекст для `call`, теперь это `slice`. А вот контекст `slice` не фиксируется, он по-прежнему ожидается в аргументе.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь все понятно и логично :)